# How to Download the broadpeak files from the encode chip-seq experiment matrix?

Tags: gene-expression, chip-seq

I have tried the SqlDatabase of Encode opened it trough R ,i have tried other packages in R, i have tried the ENCODExplorer package but none of them seems to do what i want. I have an app that asks the user which cell type and which antibody factor wants to choose in Shiny. These cell types and antibody targets are drawn from chip-seq matrix here https://genome.ucsc.edu/ENCODE/dataMatrix/encodeChipMatrixHuman.html. I want to download the .broadpeak file from the experiment that was made using the two selections of the user . I cant find where the data from this matrix are stored and for sure they are not stored in the new website database of ENCODE. 
Does anyone has an idea ??
These are some notes not all  from a what i searched

> ```
> 1)https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/vignettes/ENCODExplorer/inst/doc/ENCODExplorer.html
> New portal of ENCODE https://www.encodeproject.org/ 
> #Load the ENCODExplorer
> suppressMessages(library(ENCODExplorer))
> #Find all the files from the experiment with biosample from A549 human cell using H2AFZ as antibody target
> query_results <- searchEncode("a549 chip-seq homo sapiens h2afz") or
> search_results <- searchEncode(searchTerm = "a549 chip-seq h2afz", limit = "all")
> //downloadEncode(resultSet = search_results, resultOrigin = "searchEncode", format = "bed_broadPeak")
> cant find any broadpeak files 
>
> 2)Connect to an Oracle database(Encode sql Database) using R
> http://rprogramming.net/connect-to-database-in-r/
> channel <- odbcConnect("genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu", uid="genomep", pwd="password", believeNRows=FALSE)
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error
> #Database schema 
> install.packages("RMySQL")
> library(RMySQL)
> drv = dbDriver("MySQL")
> con = dbConnect(drv,host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu",user="genomep",pass="password")
> album = dbGetQuery(con,statement="show tables")
> Tables_in_hgcentral
> 1          blatServers
> 2                clade
> 3                 dbDb
> 4             dbDbArch
> 5            defaultDb
> 6               gbNode
> 7          genomeClade
> 8            geoIpNode
> 9            hubPublic
> 10           jorgetest
> 11       liftOverChain
> 12       liftOver_bkup
> 13           sessionDb
> 14   tableDescriptions
> 15            targetDb
> 16              userDb
> 17           wikiTrack
> 3)Not working-->https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/making-data-analytics-simpler-sql-server-and-r/
> ```

Comment: There is an FTP link from where you can download the data (I had downloaded it from there). In any case this question is off-topic because it is not at all about the bioinformatics aspect of the data.

Comment: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeRegTfbsClustered/

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold because it is not about biological or bioinformatics principles.